# SWI Prolog - Combining elements from two lists into pairs

Tags: list, prolog

How can I "join" two lists while keeping their elements's positions? Like, I have `List1 = [1,2,3]` and `List2 = [a,b,c]`. How can I get the list `[[1,a], [2,b], [3,c]]`?

I've been trying to look for built-in predicates but all I've found can't reproduce this.

Comment: Did you look at other questions? This has been answered many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
join_2_lists(L1, L2, JoinLst) :-
    must_be(list, L1),
    must_be(list, L2),
    join_2_lists_(L1, L2, JoinLst).

join_2_lists_([], [], []).
join_2_lists_([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [[H1, H2]|JoinLst]) :-
    join_2_lists_(T1, T2, JoinLst).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- join_2_lists([1, 2, 3], [a, b, c], J).
J = [[1,a],[2,b],[3,c]].
```

Comment: Why these restrictions?

Comment: The spec indicates that the two lists are provided. The spec does not ask for the code to be as general as possible, although of course that is a potential refinement/improvement. When writing this code, I had in mind a potential extension to cope with lists of unequal length, rather than focusing on generality.